# How to fix SQLite Devise Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm following a [tutorial](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/) on adding the Devise gem to Rails. One feature of the gem is generating a "user" using Devise, for further user authentication (Facebook, Twitter, etc.). I'm running into the following error:

```
== 20150906025001 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT
NULL/Users/jaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

I already have a User model in my app, that has an email, so this makes sense. However, when I try to run a migration and delete my "User" table, I'm still getting the same error.

[timestamp]_add_devise_to_users.rb:

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
change_table(:users) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  t.string   :confirmation_token
  t.datetime :confirmed_at
  t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at


  # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
  # t.timestamps null: false
end

add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
end

def self.down
# By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
# model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
end
end
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm really confused, and no documentations have seemed to help. Thanks so much.

Comment: What does your "remove users" migration look like? Or are you simple trying to reverse the migration? If it is the latter, it cannot reverse the `change_table` method, you'll need to do this manually

Comment: I have a migration called "[timestamp]_drop_users", where it just performs the "drop_table" action on my users table. This migration comes after AddDeviseToUsers one @WesFoster

Comment: This happens because the `AddUsers` migration tries to run BEFORE the `DropUsers` migration. Just comment out the `email` line for the `AddUsers` migration

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate "column name: email"

read and understand errors everytime :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is happening because you already have a column called `email` in your `User` model

You could comment (or remove) the line:

```
t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
```

and the script will continue.